# problem with loop- for: java

Tags: java, swing, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to change this code to a for loop, but i have some problems

```
panel[1].setBackground(Color.red);
            panel[2].setBackground(Color.white);
            panel[3].setBackground(Color.red);
            panel[4].setBackground(Color.white);
            panel[5].setBackground(Color.red);
            panel[6].setBackground(Color.white);
            panel[7].setBackground(Color.red);
            panel[8].setBackground(Color.white);
            panel[9].setBackground(Color.red);
            panel[10].setBackground(Color.white);
```

new code - for

```
for (int i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
                panel[(i*2)+1].setBackground(Color.red);//i think that is correct, or no?
                panel[(i*3)+1].setBackground(Color.white); //problem here
            }
```

thanks

Comment: Consider the values of `(i*2)+1` and `(i*3)+1` as your loop progresses.  One the first iteration, `i = 0`, so they will be `(0*2)+1 = 1` and `(0*3)+1 = 1`, so we're already off to a bad start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

```
for (int i = 1; i < panel.length; i++)
{
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) { panel[i].setBackground(Color.white); }
    else { panel[i].setBackground(Color.red); }   
}
```

Or a more concise expression using the ternary operator:

```
for (int i = 1; i < panel.length; i++)
{
     panel[i].setBackground( i % 2 == 0 ? Color.white : Color.red );  
}
```

**Explaination**

`%` is the modulo operator, `i % 2 == 0` when `i` is even, `!= 0` when odd.

**Caveats**

*Your array of panels referencing in your example starts at 1, arrays in Java start at ZERO, you might have a potential one off error here if you have anything in the (first) ZERO array element.*

*Using the type safe `List` classes is always better than working with arrays directly, you would not have to deal with the one off error problems you are creating by not using the first array slot.*

Comment: whats teh point of using if else conditions when you can increment an array with 2?

Comment: that would not work with a list of odd items, read what the `%` operator is for.

Comment: `i % 2 == 0 ? panel[i].setBackground(Color.white) : panel[i].setBackground(Color.red); }` this will not compile in java

Comment: @bestsss: fixed it, copy and pasted the wrong thing originally

Answer (score 8):

Use a new-style for loop:

```
int ct = 0;
for(JPanel panel : panels){
   panel.setBackground((ct % 2 == 1) ? Color.Red : Color.White);
   ct++;
}
```

Comment: +1 I would rather have a reference for current color than modulo operator on a int var though. Looks a bit cleaner that way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097601/problem-with-loop-for-java/5097696#5097696

Comment: Agree with @Oscar.  There's little point using an iterator if you have to maintain an index/count independently anyway.

Comment: meh, boolean ct = false;.... ct^=false; ; not need to an expensive mod operation;

Comment: @Fel what does that mean? a) There is an item, but you don't want to change it's color b) you are leaving the zero index of your array empty?

Comment: @Oscar, Oli, bestsss: agreed. But I had to smirk over the *expensive* mod operation. How many million iterations do you need to actually notice a difference?

Comment: @Fel: you **do** have an `[0]` you are just not putting anything in it, it is still there and it would cause this answer to fail with a `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Sean, It's not the performance but the readability ( at least in my case )

Comment: @Sean, it's an instinct. I mean to code it like that. And you can bit test if you wanna skip mod `i&1` is the same as `i%2` for positive i

Comment: @bestsss if you ask me, all bit operations should be illegal in Java. it's not C/C++ !!! :-)

Comment: @Sean, you never do any library code, do you? you do have bounds checking and absolutely type safety...  Also if you remove bit ops, java is dead on the servers, no protocols for you

Comment: This answer will fail on with a `NullPointerException` because the first item in the array is un-used and apparently `null`.

Comment: @bestsss was just teasing. I know they have their valid uses, but I avoid them where possible

Comment: @Sean, as for your remark, reminds me Josh Bloch who is on the back cover of 'Hacker's Delight' w/ some quote... but still uses the non-hacker version (loop one) for integer log2 in HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 1; i<panel.length; i++)
{
    if(i%2 == 0)
    {
        panel[i].setBackground(Color.white);
    }
    else
    {
        panel[i].setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would:

```
Color current = Color.white; 
for( Panel p : panels ) { 
   p.setBackground( current );
   current =  ( current == Color.white ? Color.red : Color.white );
}
```

Comment: hi! in the 2nd example you have red/white, in the 1st white/red. i.e. need to start w/ red (before the loop)

Comment: Removed 2nd example as only makes noise

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < length; i+=2)
{
    panel[i].setBackground(red);
    panel[i+1].setBackground(white);
}
```

Comment: this will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as well as not work odd numbers of items